# V-brake to disc brake

Tags: disc-brake, upgrades

I want to buy a new fork (a SR Suntour Raidon XC DS-LO-R if you are curious). It says that it works only with a disc brake. Guess who has a V-brake? Me. How to upgrade from V to disc and is it worth it to do it for such a thing. I ride street, light trails and I almost don't jump with the bike.

Comment: what bike do you use??

Comment: I've never liked the idea of mixing brake types on a bike.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus That sounds like a candidate for a new question - I don't see any problem with it.

Comment: Just my personal opinion, hence expressed in a comment. I wouldn't criticize anyone I saw riding a bike with two different brakes.

Answer (score 1):

This can get expensive, so check the costs before committing.

You require a disk brake caliper and lever, which might be a sealed hydraulic unit or a cable-operated one.

The caliper needs to operate on a disk rotor, and the rotor needs to fasten to the disk compatible wheel hub.

It is probably cheaper to buy a new complete disk-compatible wheel rather than rebuild your current rim onto a new disk compatible hub.

Also check the mount on the new fork - if it's for a through-axle then your new wheel needs a through-axle compatible hub. QRs seem to be vanishing.

Depending on your grip condition, you may need to replace them too.  May need to cut the old grip off to swap the brake lever.

Your tyre and tube should transfer over okay, assuming they aren't worn.

Comment: @Crggie Im kinda new and most of the terminology you use is like Chinese for me. My bike is ultra budget (it's a Drag ZX2) and the shifter is on the grip itself (twisting it upwards is gear up and vice versa) so im kinda worried about that. I maybe will commit and buy a new wheel but after all i don't need tha braking power of disc, i just need it to be compatible with the "fancy" fork.

Comment: @WindyFoxBGR You're wasting money putting a nice new fork on an "ultra budget" bike.   Save up and buy a whole bike, and use the current one as a beater.